# Is graphology a scientific method?

Tags: graphology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is graphology grounded?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/641/is-graphology-grounded)

When I walked across the street , I found the following poster.This is an advertisement for  a Graphology institute that claims to teach the "right way of writing".

[image]

I feel, it is totally absurd.

Are any of the claims in the image proved or scientifically studied ?

Comment: Nitpick - the other question is on graphology as a method of analysis, these claims seem to be that it is a way to effect change (via changing your handwriting first), rather like the Discworld "retro-phrenologists" that change your personality by putting bumps on your head with a mallet.